# Getting Error : Quarkus code generation phase has failed with code-with-quarkus project

Tags: java, maven, quarkus

D:\workspace\code-with-quarkus>mvnw compile quarkus:dev

Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.7.3.Final:generate-code (default) on project code-with-quarkus: Quarkus code generation phase has failed: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths

### POM

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>code-with-quarkus</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
        <failsafe.useModulePath>false</failsafe.useModulePath>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>2.7.3.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                        <maven.settings>${session.request.userSettingsFile.path}</maven.settings>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                                        <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

running with jdk 11

D:\workspace\code-with-quarkus>mvn package -e -x

### It looks like some problem with the plug in; unable to figure out I'm new to quarkus

full logs

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.273 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-03-06T13:00:13+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.7.3.Final:generate-code (default) on project code-with-quarkus: Quarkus code generation phase has failed: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.7.3.Final:generate-code (default) on project code-with-quarkus: Quarkus code generation phase has failed
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Quarkus code generation phase has failed
    at io.quarkus.maven.GenerateCodeMojo.generateCode (GenerateCodeMojo.java:86)
    at io.quarkus.maven.GenerateCodeMojo.doExecute (GenerateCodeMojo.java:55)
    at io.quarkus.maven.QuarkusBootstrapMojo.execute (QuarkusBootstrapMojo.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths
    at io.quarkus.paths.PathTreeWithManifest$ManifestReader.apply (PathTreeWithManifest.java:215)
    at io.quarkus.paths.PathTreeWithManifest$ManifestReader.apply (PathTreeWithManifest.java:204)
    at io.quarkus.paths.PathTreeVisit.process (PathTreeVisit.java:40)
    at io.quarkus.paths.DirectoryPathTree.apply (DirectoryPathTree.java:104)
    at io.quarkus.paths.ArchivePathTree$OpenArchivePathTree.apply (ArchivePathTree.java:202)
    at io.quarkus.paths.PathTreeWithManifest.getManifest (PathTreeWithManifest.java:97)
    at io.quarkus.paths.PathTreeWithManifest.isMultiReleaseJar (PathTreeWithManifest.java:119)
    at io.quarkus.paths.PathTreeWithManifest.getMultiReleaseMapping (PathTreeWithManifest.java:126)
    at io.quarkus.paths.DirectoryPathTree.walk (DirectoryPathTree.java:87)
    at io.quarkus.paths.ArchivePathTree$OpenArchivePathTree.walk (ArchivePathTree.java:224)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.PathTreeClassPathElement.lambda$getProvidedResources$2 (PathTreeClassPathElement.java:136)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.PathTreeClassPathElement.apply (PathTreeClassPathElement.java:111)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.PathTreeClassPathElement.getProvidedResources (PathTreeClassPathElement.java:134)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.getState (QuarkusClassLoader.java:259)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass (QuarkusClassLoader.java:429)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass (QuarkusClassLoader.java:414)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass (QuarkusClassLoader.java:464)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass (QuarkusClassLoader.java:414)
    at io.quarkus.maven.GenerateCodeMojo.generateCode (GenerateCodeMojo.java:75)
    at io.quarkus.maven.GenerateCodeMojo.doExecute (GenerateCodeMojo.java:55)
    at io.quarkus.maven.QuarkusBootstrapMojo.execute (QuarkusBootstrapMojo.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read (InflaterInputStream.java:165)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.fill (Manifest.java:498)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.readLine (Manifest.java:407)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.readLine (Manifest.java:466)
    at java.util.jar.Attributes.read (Attributes.java:378)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.read (Manifest.java:230)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init> (Manifest.java:80)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init> (Manifest.java:72)
    at io.quarkus.paths.PathTreeWithManifest$ManifestReader.apply (PathTreeWithManifest.java:213)
    at io.quarkus.paths.PathTreeWithManifest$ManifestReader.apply (PathTreeWithManifest.java:204)
    at io.quarkus.paths.PathTreeVisit.process (PathTreeVisit.java:40)
    at io.quarkus.paths.DirectoryPathTree.apply (DirectoryPathTree.java:104)
    at io.quarkus.paths.ArchivePathTree$OpenArchivePathTree.apply (ArchivePathTree.java:202)
    at io.quarkus.paths.PathTreeWithManifest.getManifest (PathTreeWithManifest.java:97)
    at io.quarkus.paths.PathTreeWithManifest.isMultiReleaseJar (PathTreeWithManifest.java:119)
    at io.quarkus.paths.PathTreeWithManifest.getMultiReleaseMapping (PathTreeWithManifest.java:126)
    at io.quarkus.paths.DirectoryPathTree.walk (DirectoryPathTree.java:87)
    at io.quarkus.paths.ArchivePathTree$OpenArchivePathTree.walk (ArchivePathTree.java:224)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.PathTreeClassPathElement.lambda$getProvidedResources$2 (PathTreeClassPathElement.java:136)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.PathTreeClassPathElement.apply (PathTreeClassPathElement.java:111)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.PathTreeClassPathElement.getProvidedResources (PathTreeClassPathElement.java:134)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.getState (QuarkusClassLoader.java:259)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass (QuarkusClassLoader.java:429)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass (QuarkusClassLoader.java:414)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass (QuarkusClassLoader.java:464)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass (QuarkusClassLoader.java:414)
    at io.quarkus.maven.GenerateCodeMojo.generateCode (GenerateCodeMojo.java:75)
    at io.quarkus.maven.GenerateCodeMojo.doExecute (GenerateCodeMojo.java:55)
    at io.quarkus.maven.QuarkusBootstrapMojo.execute (QuarkusBootstrapMojo.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Perhaps try clearing out your `~/.m2/repository` directory and try again?

Comment: looks like local repo problem see https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/4671

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some of the packages are broken while downloading.
Try fixing this by deleting the contents of the .m2\repository directory.

Try this command

```
rd /s /q %USERPROFILE%.m2\repository
```

or delete it via Explorer.